# request sql of search in database sqlite

Tags: android

I have an edit text where the user write the name
I want the syntax of request "select name from table where name begin of the contain of the edit text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... `WHERE name LIKE 'edit text%'` - for begin

... `WHERE name LIKE '%edit text%'` - for contain